# Suggesting an IDE to new Python programmers

Tags: discussion, new-users

I often come across questions (by users that are relatively new to programming) that would have never been posted here if they had been using an IDE that can easily detect a missing `'` and inform the user.

Those questions are usually of no use to anyone (Typographical errors or 100th duplicate) and have a trivial "solution": use an IDE.

On top of that, I feel like my IDE has helped me speed up my learning by *a lot* e.g. warning me of [default mutable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

As a conclusion, suggesting IDE usage can decrease our wasted time a lot, and increase new users' productivity.

---

How should I phrase my IDE-suggesting comment, in order to avoid promoting a specific IDE?

I am only familiar with PyCharm, and questions like ["What IDE to use in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) contain too much information and some of it can become or already is outdated.

Comment: Is a missing `'` a typical Python mistake? Just "IDE" is a bit broad - different languages have different IDEs, with different capabilities. Personally I am content with `clang` - but a C compiler is something else than a Python syntax checker.

Comment: @Jongware Should I make the question specific to Python? I m only familiar with Python. (feel free to edit as you see fit)

Comment: What are you actually proposing to *do*, here? If you want to know what to put in a comment, just tell them to use an IDE that can highlight syntax errors; if you mention PyCharm specifically, something like *"I use PyCharm, but other options are available"* would suffice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm asking what type of comment should I use in order to avoid promoting PyCharm. I imagine leaving 10-50 of "I use PyCharm, but other options are available" would be considered promotion.

Comment: Then just suggest *"an IDE"*, if that makes you uncomfortable. I doubt others would see it that way, FWIW.

Comment: Or just send them to e.g. http://sopython.com/wiki/Python_IDEs

Comment: @jonrsharpe The sopython suggestions looks very appealing. It's probably what I ll be doing.

Comment: "Throw away everything you have and what you learned so far" is never an appropriate answer.  You can post a tooling recommendation in a comment but do expect it to be ignored or be argued about.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably leave a comment. Don't leave an answer - it won't really answer the question, and it will bring a spammy feeling that you are nervous about.

> Hey! What IDE are you using? Better IDEs will help you understand the syntax, and help find other errors in your code. May I recommend PyCharm?

<sup>Speaking of which, I need to get something better than idle... -_-</sup>

Here's a couple pluses:

Comments can't be marked spam. You won't get -100 rep in any case. It's probably the best way you can use to get your point across.

I wouldn't worry about promoting a specific IDE. If you have something to recommend, then recommend that one.

Comment: Comments **can** be flagged and a user investigated through mod action.

Comment: @DeerHunter  one really need to try hard to get in trouble with suggestion to use widely used tools.

Comment: @DeerHunter Also, I doubt something bad would happen, even if the comments were flagged. Worst comes to worse, they'd get removed. Obviously, not all the comments should really be that exact text, and should probably be personalized to fit the question, but I can't imagine anything bad happening with those actions.

Comment: If you want something better than IDLE but don't like PyCharm (and you write in other languages, too? or just want a cool editor) I recommend http://atom.io, which even has a built-in package manager and a package for running scripts inside the editor.

Comment: @cat Thanks! I work with both Python and Java, and right now I've got Eclipse as the Java IDE, but I've never bothered to really update IDLE... :/ I'll look into Atom. Thanks Again :D